# Add a primary key to an existing table without downtime

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using rails 6

I need to add a primary key to a table that's being written to actively without downtime. **This is also limited by existing processes in which an updated `db/schema.rb` would be committed and deployed but the deploy must work before and after the migration.** Normally this isn't an issue as long as there are no code references that aren't compatible with the schema changes, but rails is doing some magic when it sees a primary key in `db/schema.rb`.

I've tried adding `self.primary_key = nil` and `self.ignored_columns = [:id]` to the model but both result in the same error I get without them when trying to update records:
`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'tablename.' in 'where clause'`

Is this possible without creating a new table?

Answer (score 1):

I am not a ruby on rails expert but I have concerns that this will work. If you add another primary key to a table, the only way to unambiguously identify a datarow is providing all old keys and the new key to the database.
My guess would be that ruby on rails enforces that each datarow can be unambiguously being identified. Otherwise ruby on rails would not be able to ensure that DB queries just return one single row or just a single row will be modified.

The ruby on rails API documentation on *ignored_columns=(columns)* states:

> Sets the columns names the model should ignore. Ignored columns won't have attribute accessors defined, and won't be referenced in SQL queries.

> A common usage pattern for this method is to ensure all references to an attribute have been removed and deployed, before a migration to drop the column from the database has been deployed and run. Using this two step approach to dropping columns ensures there is no code that raises errors due to having a cached schema in memory at the time the schema migration is run.

I guess even in this use case of removing columns, you won't be able to use ignored_columns.